# Apply two Date Method consecutively on single object?

Tags: javascript

I hope you have well with nice pleasure.

Please find me it is possible to apply two date method on single object.
Because when we apply single method on date object answer is return in 'String' format. and Date method does not apply on string, only requires Object.

Code is here

```
        var date =  new Date();

        utc = date.getUTCString();

        // Problem is here i am want to conver
        // utc to object, then apply another function.

        var str  = utc.toDateString(); 
        // here is error shown in Console window

        document.write(utc);
```

My intention to ask answer. 
how can I apply two Date method on single Date object?

I believe , I am receiving good and positive reply soon.

Comment: You can use jquery to select class and id selectors descendants

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for this:

```js
document.querySelector('#yes input').value = 'Changed!';
```

```html
<div id="yes">
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="submit">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am obliged you @user3762406

Comment: Please close my question, i got it my answer.

Thank you once again.

Comment: If you accept this (or any other...) answer, your question will be closed, *and* you'll get some positive reputation.

Comment: Dear Amin, please find me how can i accept this answer explicitly inform to stackoverflow, mean where is accept button?

Comment: @user3762406 - click the checkmark next to the answer. You might want to read [tour] as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) 
This will achieve the expression you stated. As for returning elements by CSS rule:

You would have to loop through an array of elements and check it's styles, [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html) is useful for getting styles